# Return a corresponding variable from another table in SQL?

Tags: sql

Say I have two tables, `Employees`:

```
first    last        ID    hire         terminated    wage
------   ---------   ---   ----------   -----------   ----
Ruth     Halburg     1     2010-05-15   2017-03-01    2000
Sally    Hallson     2     2010-08-20   NULL          5000
Merry    Hallway     3     2011-01-24   NULL          3000
```

and `RoutineReviews`:

```
ID      EmployeeID   RevDate
-----   ----------   -------------
10      1            2015-02-02
11      2            2014-11-28
12      1            2014-09-03
```

Where `ID` in the first table corresponds with `EmployeeID`; how would I write a query that returns all the employees who have never had a review (e.g. employee 3), sorted by their hire date?

```
SELECT first last Employee.ID hire terminated wage
FROM Employees, RoutineReviews
WHERE Employees.ID != RoutineReviews.EmployeeID;
```

This doesn't seem to be working for some reason.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

We can use an `EXISTS` clause here:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RoutineReviews r WHERE e.ID = r.EmployeeID)
ORDER BY hire;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Left join is handy here:

```
SELECT e.first, e.last, e.ID, e.hire, e.terminated, e.wage
FROM Employees e
LEFT JOIN RoutineReviews r
on e.ID = r.EmployeeID
WHERE r.EmployeeID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `LEFT JOIN` here

```
SELECT 
 Employees.*
FROM 
 Employees
LEFT JOIN 
 RoutineReviews
ON 
 Employees.ID = RoutineReviews.EmployeeID   
WHERE
 RoutineReviews.ID IS NULL
```

Or with `NOT IN` i advice you not to use this because MySQL tends to optimize badly with co-related subqueries. 
The query is here for reference.

```
SELECT 
 Employees.*
FROM 
 Employees
WHERE
 Employees.ID NOT IN (
  SELECT 
   RoutineReviews.EmployeeID   
  FROM 
   RoutineReviews
  WHERE
   RoutineReviews.EmployeeID = Employees.ID
)
```